# Get app activity log using graph-facebook-api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

How to get activity log of specific app in facebook using Graph Faceebok API?
For example I use shazam and it posts to my wall new songs.

I can see these songs on my wall and also in activity_log url.

[https://www.facebook.com/NAME?sk=allactivity&privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=app_210827375150](https://www.facebook.com/pavel.vlasov?sk=allactivity&privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=app_210827375150)

Could you help me how to get activity log data from specific app. ex. Shazam.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graph API provide filter by app like you see in activity log.

For example :

```
app: shazam 
id: 210827375150
```

Graph API for this app activity 
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?filter=app_210827375150

You can test it here
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fhome%3Ffilter%3Dapp_210827375150

And for the document:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home

Comment: How do you find app ID numbers for particular apps?

Comment: You can use fql to query appid by  app name   
`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+app_id,namespace,category+FROM+application+WHERE+namespace=%22**<APP NAME>**%22`

for example id of Farmville 2  
`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+app_id,namespace,category+FROM+application+WHERE+namespace=%22farmville-two%22`